# Busca com REGEX no VI

Tags: linux, regex

Tenho uma regex que é válida conforme o teste do site https://regex101.com/ , porem no vi ela não funciona:

```
2017\/04\/26 12:24:(.*)(89418644)
```

Seguem um exemplo que esta REGEX deveria casar:

INFO| 2017/04/26 12:24:15.019 | [OrderEntryAvailableOutgoingFlowListPopulator] 89418644 OK

Acredito que seja alguma regra de sintaxe para utilização de grupos na busca do vi, mas ainda não consegui identificar.

Comment: O "vi" seria o editor de texto de linha de comando? Tem como colocar um exemplo do texto que você está procurando?

Comment: Editei a pergunta adicionando o texto que a REGEX deveria localizar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao realizar um pesquisa no [`vi`](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html) ele não interpreta direto que o que você esta usando é uma REGEX, de tal forma que o que ele pesquisa na verdade é um `String`.

Assim você deve usar a mesma lógoca quando de passa um String para REGEX, e é necessário escapar os caracteres especiais.

`2017\/04\/26 12:24:\(.*\)\(89418644\)`

#### Adendo

Se você esta apenas pesquisando você poderia simplesmente remover os grupos :

`2017\/04\/26 12:24:.*89418644`

Caso voce esteja trabalhando com replace a um modificador que auxilia nisso `\v` :

`:%s/\v2017\/04\/26 12:24:(.*)(89418644)/REPLACE/`

Fonte [Vim Regex Capture Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19902089/3937493)